Horizontal Scrollable Table
The table is scrollable, but it's out of container. I want the table to be scrollable horizontally but not out of the container
Current table
What I want
see the picture
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
main {
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
th {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1.5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.275);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.107);
}
td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1.5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.275);
}


<body>

  <main>

    <h1>Table</h1>

    <table><thead><tr><th align="left">Table Heading 1</th><th align="left">Table Heading 2</th><th align="center">Center align</th><th align="right">Right align</th><th align="left">Table Heading 5</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td align="left">Item 1</td><td align="left">Item 2</td><td align="center">Item 3</td><td align="right">Item 4</td><td align="left">Item 5</td></tr><tr><td align="left">Item 1</td><td align="left">Item 2</td><td align="center">Item 3</td><td align="right">Item 4</td><td align="left">Item 5</td></tr><tr><td align="left">Item 1</td><td align="left">Item 2</td><td align="center">Item 3</td><td align="right">Item 4</td><td align="left">Item 5</td></tr><tr><td align="left">Item 1</td><td align="left">Item 2</td><td align="center">Item 3</td><td align="right">Item 4</td><td align="left">Item 5</td></tr><tr><td align="left">Item 1</td><td align="left">Item 2</td><td align="center">Item 3</td><td align="right">Item 4</td><td align="left">Item 5</td></tr></tbody></table>

  </main>

</body>


Put your table inside a div styled with overflow: auto.


body {
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.table-wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

th, td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1.5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.275);
}

th {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.107);
}

th:nth-child(3), td:nth-child(3) {
  text-align: center;
}

th:nth-child(4), td:nth-child(4) {
  text-align: right;
}
<main>

  <h1>Table</h1>

  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Table Heading 1</th>
          <th>Table Heading 2</th>
          <th>Center align</th>
          <th>Right align</th>
          <th>Table Heading 5</th>
          <th>Table Heading 6</th>
          <th>Table Heading 7</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Item 1</td>
          <td>Item 2</td>
          <td>Item 3</td>
          <td>Item 4</td>
          <td>Item 5</td>
          <td>Item 6</td>
          <td>Item 7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Item 1</td>
          <td>Item 2</td>
          <td>Item 3</td>
          <td>Item 4</td>
          <td>Item 5</td>
          <td>Item 6</td>
          <td>Item 7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Item 1</td>
          <td>Item 2</td>
          <td>Item 3</td>
          <td>Item 4</td>
          <td>Item 5</td>
          <td>Item 6</td>
          <td>Item 7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Item 1</td>
          <td>Item 2</td>
          <td>Item 3</td>
          <td>Item 4</td>
          <td>Item 5</td>
          <td>Item 6</td>
          <td>Item 7</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</main>



